# Deriving, diff b/w angles of minute and hour hands =11m/2-30h

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I encountered this formula, $x=\frac{11m}2-30h$, where x is the angle between the minute hand and hour hand of a clock. m being minutes and h being hours. Ex- at 3:20, m=20 and h=3, so, x=20 degree from the above formula. It's a very handy formula. But I wonder how to derive it.

I see that minute hand makes 6 degrees in 1 minute and hour hand makes half degree. So, the difference in their angles after m minutes will be $\frac{11m}2$. But from where did we get 30h?

Comment: More precisely $\left|\frac{11m}{2}−30h\right|$

Comment: To account for the reflex angle as well (and omit any negative angles in calculation for convenience)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the hour hand, in $1$ minutes rotates  $\displaystyle\frac12^\circ,$

So, in $h$ hour $m$ minute $\displaystyle =60h+m$ minute it will rotate  $\displaystyle \left(\frac{60h+m}2\right)^\circ=\left(30h+\frac m2\right)^\circ$

Similarly, in $h$ hour $m$ minute the minute hand will rotate $\displaystyle 6(60h+m)^\circ\equiv 6m^\circ\pmod{360^\circ}$  assuming $h$ to be some integer

Now find the difference

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the angle between minute and hour hand is $\theta$ when the time is $H: x$ (hour: minutes format), i.e., it is $x$ minutes past $H$' o clock.

Initially, at $H'$o clock, the minute hand is at $12$ and the hour hand is at $H$.

Minute hand moves at a speed of $360^o/60 \min=6^o/\min$, while the hour hand's speed is $0.5^o/\min$.

Analysing the clock for an hour $H$ to $H+1 \mod (12) $'o clock, there are two cases:

Case $1$: the minute hand is anti-clockwise to the hour hand.

Case $2$: the hour hand is anti-clockwise to the minute hand.

Case $1$: the minute hand moves $x$ minutes from $12$. So the minute hand has moved min. hand speed $\times x=6x$ degrees. During this time (i.e., $x$ minutes), the hour hand has moved hour hand speed $\times x=0.5 x$ degrees. At this stage, the hour hand makes an angle of $30H+0.5x$ degrees from the vertical upward direction. Since, the minute hand is anti-clockwise to the hour hand, the angle between the two hands is $=0.5x+30H-6x= 30H- 11/2x$.

Case $2$: this gives the angle as $11/2x- 30H$.

So $\theta=|11/2x-30H|$.